# Encode/Decode id to int(7)

Tags: php, hash, encode

I have a table of users each of them has `ID` (autoincrement) stored in table. I am trying to "recalculate" (encode/decode/hash) this number to another number (`UID`) that is 7 numbers long (I dont know the term that is called this operation). It can be guessable, I just need to "grow" the length of ID to int(7), and I do not want to set autoinctement to `100000` in database.

I am not trying to get `ID` from `UID` I am trying to achieve this

```
id -> calculation -> unique id for user
8 -> calculation -> 1234567
8 -> calculation -> 1234567 
9 -> calculation -> 2569845
1234567 -> calculation -> "not possible" (not necessary just it is not needed)
```

I've tried funny thing like this (I've tried all kinds of derivations of `md5`, `sha` in different order and I figured that is not the way) is there any native php function that would do this? (`!uniqid()`)

```
$new = substr(preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", "", md5(sha1($i))), 0, 7);
```

This one is great but it has conflicts in it (for loop 1 to 10k)

```
Already in array new: $filled[4268] = 1050014 array old: $filled[2742] = 1050014
Already in array new: $filled[7278] = 3309143 array old: $filled[1682] = 3309143
Already in array new: $filled[9676] = 1785301 array old: $filled[8310] = 1785301
```

that means that `ID` with 4268 and 2742 would have same `UID`

Comment: I'd like to have int(7) in database so I can create `EAN8` barcode. I've edited the "purpose" in original Q.

Comment: 7 is very short when you doing 10k

Comment: How many users do you have? Also, can you provide your main problem?

Comment: System itself wont have so many users at a time (max 50). But some may be deleted/banned and some may be added in next lets say 10 years. I need "buletproof" solution so it can hold at least 10k users.

Comment: you can use str_pad to pad the number ta a 7 digit number

Comment: @Kyslik, what is wrong with autoincrement?

Comment: @sectus, nothing really, I use it in every table, but in this case I just need generate from whatever number is passed as argument to generate another number that is long 7 numbers (or less but still unique in matter of UIDs).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by others, this is a ridiculous requirement. Any sane system would just use the transparent 1:1 mapping. But I guess you must do what you have been told to, so...

Let's expand this to account for 65535 IDs. This is the upper bound of an unsigned short, which requires 2 bytes - 16 bits - to store as an integer. The desired output is 7 bytes, so by moving some bits around we can generate unique, reversible IDs derived directly from the original input number that are, on the face of it, nothing to do with the input.

But... we still need the ASCII representation to be numeric. No problem - we just encode the numbers into 3-bit chunks, and OR it with 0x30 - this means that every encoded byte with have an ASCII code point of between 0 and 7.

Once we realise that, all we need to do is pick a system. In the interests of simplicity, I'll just step through bits 1-16 and scatter them through the 7 output bytes evenly. this will still produce something that looks fairly predictable - and especially at the low end it will have a lot of zeros in it, so I'll spice it up a bit by XOR-ing the result with a known key.

```
<?php

// Produces a key of the supplied length
// This will always produce the same result, it just alternates
// the least significant 3 bits of every output byte
function generate_xor_key($length)
{
    $result = array_fill(0, $length, 0);

    for ($i = 0, $bit = 1; $i < $length; $i++) {
        for ($j = 0; $j < 3; $j++, $bit++) {
            $result[$i] |= ($bit % 2) << $j;
        }
    }

    return implode('', array_map('chr', $result));
}

// Encode an ID
// If using a custom key this can be supplied in the 4th argument
// Keys must always be strings with all the bytes in the range 0x00 - 0x08
function encode_id($id, $encodedLength = 7, $rawBits = 16, $key = null)
{
    // Because we are encoding the number into the least significant 3 bits,
    // it doesn't make sense for $rawBits > $encodedLength * 3
    $maxRawBits = $encodedLength * 3;
    if ($rawBits > $maxRawBits) {
        trigger_error('encode_id(): $rawBits must be no more than 3 times greater than $encodedLength');
        return false;
    }

    // Get a usable key
    if ($key === null) {
        $key = generate_xor_key($encodedLength);
    }

    // Start with all bytes at ASCII 0
    $result = array_fill(0, $encodedLength, 0x30);

    // Extract each relevant bit from the input and store it in the output bytes
    for ($position = 0; $position < $rawBits; $position++) {
        $bit = (($id >> $position) & 0x01) << floor($position / $encodedLength);
        $index = $position % $encodedLength;
        $result[$index] |= $bit;
    }

    // Pad the remaining bits with alternation
    // This is purely cosmetic for the output
    for (; $position < $maxRawBits; $position++) {
        $index = $position % $encodedLength;
        $bit = ($position % 2) << floor($position / $encodedLength);
        $result[$index] |= $bit;
    }

    // Convert the result to an ascii string
    return implode('', array_map('chr', $result)) ^ $key;
}

function decode_id($id, $encodedLength = 7, $rawBits = 16, $key = null)
{
    // Get a usable key
    if ($key === null) {
        $key = generate_xor_key($encodedLength);
    }

    // Convert the string to our original bytes array
    $bytes = array_map(
        'ord',
        str_split(
            str_pad($id, $encodedLength, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT) ^ $key,
            1
        )
    );

    $result = 0;

    // Put the number back together
    for ($position = 0; $position < $rawBits; $position++) {
        $index = $position % $encodedLength;
        $bit = (($bytes[$index] >> floor($position / $encodedLength)) & 0x01) << $position;
        $result |= $bit;
    }

    return $result;
}
```

http://codepad.org/hfZ4YBKI

Every consecutive ID is very similar to the previous - usually only 1 digit has changed - but to the untrained it is a long way from a standard vertical counter.

As implemented above, this mechanism can can actually account for 21 bits of entropy, so that's 2097152 unique IDs that can be generated (including zero).

Comment: Very nice answer, this is what I was "looking" for. Very well explained thank you.

Comment: _sidenote_: It could generate any number not just 0-7. (it just has to be 7 characters (numbers) long. eg: 1237896. I didn't know how to say it in english as I am not native speaker therefore I used sql notation `int(7)`. Once again beautiful solution.

Answer (score 0):

I all your existing IDs are less than 8999999 then just add 1000000 to the existing IDS.